# Mule Application deploy SAP connector issue

Tags: mule, config, pom.xml, anypoint-studio, sapjco3

I am trying to deploy an Application in Mule 3 with Anypoint Studio version 6.6.0, but getting several errors in the problems tab, it seems it doesn't find the SAP connector dependency though I have included it in the pom.xml file of the application and the specified libraries such as libsapjco3.jnilib, libsapjco3.so, sapidoc3.jar, sapjco3.dll, sapjco3.jar in the directory /lib of the application. What am I doing wrong how do I have to install this connector? I apreciate any help.

Here the problems list:
[image]

Here the source of the error in the config.xml:
[image]

Here I attach the config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:apikit="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit"
    xmlns:sap="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sap"
    xmlns:secure-property-placeholder="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/secure-property-placeholder"
    xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:db="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:core="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/apikit/current/mule-apikit.xsd http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sap http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/sap/current/mule-sap.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/db/current/mule-db.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-current.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/secure-property-placeholder http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/secure-property-placeholder/current/mule-secure-property-placeholder.xsd">


    
    <secure-property-placeholder:config
        name="Secure_Property_Placeholder" key="${prod.key}"
        location="classpath:common.properties,${mule.env}.properties"
        doc:name="Secure Property Placeholder" />

    <http:listener-config name="httpListenerConfig" host="0.0.0.0" port="8091" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <apikit:config name="apiConfig" raml="api.raml" consoleEnabled="false" doc:name="Router"/>
    <context:property-placeholder location="api.properties" />
    
        <sap:connector name="SAP_R3_DRE" jcoAsHost="172.20.103.141" jcoUser="MULECOMM" jcoPasswd="HOLIDAY1" jcoSysnr="00" jcoClient="150" jcoLang="EN" validateConnections="true" doc:name="SAP"/>
    <sap:connector name="SAP_R3_QRE" jcoAsHost="172.20.103.125" jcoUser="FR_MBSUPPLY" jcoPasswd="PREMIER00" jcoSysnr="00" jcoClient="700" jcoLang="EN" validateConnections="true" doc:name="SAP"/>
    <sap:connector name="SAP_S4_DRE" jcoAsHost="10.72.0.8" jcoUser="MULECOMM" jcoPasswd="PREMIER00" jcoSysnr="00" jcoClient="200" jcoLang="EN" validateConnections="true" doc:name="SAP"/>
    
    <sap:connector name="SAP_R3" jcoAsHost="${SAP_R3_HOST}" jcoUser="${SAP_R3_USER}" jcoPasswd="${SAP_R3_PASSWORD}" jcoSysnr="${SAP_R3_SYSNR}" jcoClient="${SAP_R3_CLIENT}" jcoLang="${SAP_R3_LANG}" validateConnections="true" doc:name="SAP"/>
    <sap:connector name="SAP_S4" jcoAsHost="${SAP_S4_HOST}" jcoUser="${SAP_S4_USER}" jcoPasswd="${SAP_S4_PASSWORD}" jcoSysnr="${SAP_S4_SYSNR}" jcoClient="${SAP_S4_CLIENT}" jcoLang="${SAP_S4_LANG}" validateConnections="true" doc:name="SAP"/>
    
    
    <custom-transformer class="net.inspira.api.transformers.map.MapCollectionIncludeExcludeElements"
        name="map-include-exclude-transformer" doc:name="map-include-exclude-transformer" />
    
    <custom-transformer
        class="net.inspira.api.transformers.credentials.AreasTokenTransformer"
        name="areas-token-transformer" doc:name="Java" />
    <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="JSONMapper" name="JSONMapper"
            class="net.inspira.api.transformers.json.ObjectToJsonMapperSAP" />
    </spring:beans>

    <configuration doc:name="Configuration">
        <expression-language>

            <import class="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.JsonStringEncoder" />


            <global-functions>
                def quoteJSONString(s) {
                return
                String.valueOf(JsonStringEncoder.getInstance().quoteAsString(s))
                }
            </global-functions>
        </expression-language>
    </configuration>

</mule>
```

Also I attach my pom.xml if it's needed:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>sap-api-supply</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
    <packaging>mule</packaging>
    <name>Mule sap-api-supply Application</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <mule.version>3.9.2</mule.version>
        <mule.tools.version>1.1</mule.tools.version>
        <mule-transport-sap.version>3.0.0</mule-transport-sap.version>
        <sapjco.version>3.0.14</sapjco.version>
        <sapidoc.version>3.0.12</sapidoc.version>
        <lib.directory>${project.build.directory}/lib</lib.directory>
        <native.lib.directory>${lib.directory}/${envClassifier}</native.lib.directory>
    </properties>



    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dos-i386</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>windows</family>
                    <arch>i386</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>ntintel</envClassifier>
                <envType>dll</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>sapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>windows-i386</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>windows</family>
                    <arch>i386</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>ntintel</envClassifier>
                <envType>dll</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>sapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dos-x86</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>dos</family>
                    <arch>x86</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>ntintel</envClassifier>
                <envType>dll</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>sapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>windows-x86</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>windows</family>
                    <arch>x86</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>ntintel</envClassifier>
                <envType>dll</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>sapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dos-x86_64</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>dos</family>
                    <arch>x86_64</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>ntamd64</envClassifier>
                <envType>dll</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>sapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>windows-x86_64</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>windows</family>
                    <arch>x86_64</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>ntamd64</envClassifier>
                <envType>dll</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>sapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dos-amd64</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>dos</family>
                    <arch>amd64</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>ntamd64</envClassifier>
                <envType>dll</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>sapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>windows-amd64</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <family>windows</family>
                    <arch>amd64</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>ntamd64</envClassifier>
                <envType>dll</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>sapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>linux-i386</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>linux</name>
                    <arch>i386</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>linuxintel</envClassifier>
                <envType>so</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>libsapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>linux-x86</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>linux</name>
                    <arch>x86</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>linuxintel</envClassifier>
                <envType>so</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>libsapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>linux-x86_64</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>linux</name>
                    <arch>x86_64</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>linuxx86_64</envClassifier>
                <envType>so</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>libsapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>linux-amd64</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>linux</name>
                    <arch>amd64</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>linuxx86_64</envClassifier>
                <envType>so</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>libsapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>macosx-i386</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>mac os x</name>
                    <arch>i386</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>darwinintel</envClassifier>
                <envType>jnilib</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>libsapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>macosx-x86</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>mac os x</name>
                    <arch>x86</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>darwinintel</envClassifier>
                <envType>jnilib</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>libsapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>macosx-x86_64</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>mac os x</name>
                    <arch>x86_64</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>darwinintel64</envClassifier>
                <envType>jnilib</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>libsapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>macosx-amd64</id>
            <activation>
                <os>
                    <name>mac os x</name>
                    <arch>amd64</arch>
                </os>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <envClassifier>darwinintel64</envClassifier>
                <envType>jnilib</envType>
                <native.lib.filename>libsapjco3</native.lib.filename>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>studio</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>runtime</name>
                    <value>studio</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <source>1.7</source>
                            <target>1.7</target>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-native-lib-for-unit-tests</id>
                                <phase>process-sources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                                    <outputDirectory>${native.lib.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                    <artifactItems>
                                        <!-- We use maven profiles to choose the native library according 
                                            to architecture and operating system -->
                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>com.sap.conn.jco</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>sapjco3</artifactId>
                                            <type>${envType}</type>
                                            <classifier>${envClassifier}</classifier>
                                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                            <destFileName>${native.lib.filename}.${envType}</destFileName>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                        <!-- If the target platform differ from your development platform, 
                                            you can add the native library uncommenting the following block Note that 
                                            you must set the following elements accordingly: type, classifier, outputDirectory 
                                            and destFileName -->

                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>com.sap.conn.jco</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>sapjco3</artifactId>
                                            <type>so</type>
                                            <classifier>linuxx86_64</classifier>
                                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                            <outputDirectory>${lib.directory}/linuxx86_64</outputDirectory>
                                            <destFileName>libsapjco3.so</destFileName>
                                        </artifactItem>

                                    </artifactItems>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy-jco-libs-unit-tests</id>
                                <phase>process-sources</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                                    <outputDirectory>${lib.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                    <artifactItems>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>com.sap.conn.jco</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>sapjco3</artifactId>
                                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                            <destFileName>sapjco3.jar</destFileName>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>com.sap.conn.idoc</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>sapidoc3</artifactId>
                                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                            <destFileName>sapidoc3.jar</destFileName>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>mule-transport-sap</artifactId>
                                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                            <destFileName>mule-transport-sap-${mule-transport-sap.version}.jar</destFileName>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                    </artifactItems>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                    <plugin>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>add-sap-jars</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target>
                                        <zip destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.zip" update="true">
                                            <zipfileset dir="${project.build.directory}/lib" prefix="lib"/>
                                        </zip>
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                </plugins>
            </build>

        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-app-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.tools.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                     <sharedLibraries>
                                                <sharedLibrary>
                                                        <groupId>net.inspira.api</groupId>
                                                        <artifactId>api-transformers</artifactId>
                                                </sharedLibrary>
                                                <sharedLibrary>
                                                        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
                                                        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                    </sharedLibraries>
                    <copyToAppsDirectory>true</copyToAppsDirectory>
                    <inclusions>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>com.mulesoft.security</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mule-module-security-property-placeholder</artifactId>
                        </inclusion>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mule-transport-sap</artifactId>
                        

</inclusion>
    

            <inclusion>
                        <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mule-module-apikit-soap</artifactId>
                    </inclusion>

                        <inclusion>
                                <groupId>3284c114-3570-4feb-a444-7d90b56935a3</groupId>
                                <artifactId>basetis-sap-connector</artifactId>
                            </inclusion>
                       
                        </inclusions>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>project</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>add-resource</id>
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>add-resource</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <resources>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>src/main/app/</directory>
                                    </resource>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>mappings/</directory>
                                    </resource>
                                    <resource>
                                        <directory>src/main/api/</directory>
                                    </resource>
                                </resources>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
        <!-- Mule Dependencies -->
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Xml configuration -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-core-ee</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Xml configuration -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.modules</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config-ee</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Mule Transports -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-transport-file</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-transport-http</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-transport-jdbc-ee</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-transport-jms-ee</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mule.transports</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-transport-vm</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- Mule Modules -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-module-scripting</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-module-xml</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- SAP Dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mulesoft.muleesb.transports</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-transport-sap</artifactId>
                <version>${mule-transport-sap.version}</version>
    
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sap.conn.jco</groupId>
                <artifactId>sapjco3</artifactId>
                <version>${sapjco.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sap.conn.idoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>sapidoc3</artifactId>
                <version>${sapidoc.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!-- for testing -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.version}</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-module-apikit</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mulesoft.weave</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-plugin-weave</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-module-spring-config</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-module-json</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.inspira.api</groupId>
                <artifactId>api-internal-security</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
             <dependency>
                <groupId>net.inspira.api</groupId>
                <artifactId>api-transformers</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.inspira.api</groupId>
                <artifactId>api-connection</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                <version>11.2.0.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.mulesoft.security</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-module-security-property-placeholder</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.2</version>
            </dependency>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-module-apikit-soap</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1</version>
            </dependency>
                      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
    <!--     Cloud Areas -->
         <dependency>
      <groupId>3284c114-3570-4feb-a444-7d90b56935a3</groupId>
      <artifactId>basetis-sap-connector</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.5</version>
    
    </dependency>
    <!--     Cloud Areas -->
    
    <!--     Cloud Mule -->
    <!--     <dependency> -->
    <!--             <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId> -->
    <!--             <artifactId>basetis-sap-connector</artifactId> -->
    <!--             <version>1.1.1</version> -->
    <!--         </dependency> -->
    <!--     Cloud Mule -->
    
        
        <dependency>
                            <groupId>net.inspira.api</groupId>
                            <artifactId>api-transformers</artifactId>
                            <version>2.0.0</version>
                    </dependency>
    <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
                            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
                            <version>1.1.1</version>
                    </dependency>
    
    </dependencies>
    
        <repositories>
    <!--    Repository Areas -->
        <repository>
        <id>Repository</id>
        <name>Exchange Repository</name>
        <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/organizations/3284c114-3570-4feb-a444-7d90b56935a3/maven</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
      </repository>
      <!--  Repository Areas -->
            <repository>
                <id>Central</id>
                <name>Central</name>
                <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>mulesoft-releases</id>
                <name>MuleSoft Releases Repository</name>
                <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
                <layout>default</layout>
            </repository>
        <repository>
                <id>anypoint-exchange</id>
                <name>Exchange Repository</name>
                <url>https://maven.anypoint.mulesoft.com/api/v1/organizations/3284c114-3570-4feb-a444-7d90b56935a3/maven</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
        <pluginRepositories>
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>mulesoft-release</id>
                <name>mulesoft release repository</name>
                <layout>default</layout>
                <url>http://repository.mulesoft.org/releases/</url>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>false</enabled>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
        </pluginRepositories>
    
    
    
    </project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely not in the Mule SAP connector but in using SAP client libraries. There are several steps needed to use SAP client libraries. You seem to have followed at least some of them, so the problem could be in missing the remaining ones:

- Ensure SAP dependencies are installed in your local Maven directory with the exact names, group, packaging, classifier and version used in the pom.
- Change the Maven Settings to activate the studio profile

  - Go to Run -> Run Configurations...
  - Select your mavenized project
  - Go to the Maven Settings tab
  - Enter the following argument: -Druntime=studio

Full instructions are available at https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-use-Maven-to-add-SAP-Connector-dependencies

Comment: Thank you for your response but I already did what you suggested and still get the same error, I updated the question with a screenshoot with the lines that apparently throw the error, any idea of how to fix it?